# How can I change the application icon shown by alt-tab in ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, icons, alt-tab

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal), and I'd like to change the application icon that's shown by alt-tab. Since both Chromium browser and Eclipse use a blue ball for their icon it's really easy to select the wrong one when alt-tabbing (they both also display a screenshot of the window - but this is often white with some code displayed in both applications).

Is there a common location for the icons displayed by alt-tab, and can I get in and change one of them? If not, does anyone know where Eclipse or Chromium keep their icons that they give to the OS?

I tried changing the icon in the launcher, but it didn't change the icon used by alt-tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just edit the application icon from Preferences.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's the change I meant when I changed the icon in the launcher - but sadly it doesn't change the icon when alt-tabbing, only in the launch menu.

Comment: However, this works in 11.10, so I'll mark it accepted :)